# Unfamiliar with technique to solve pre-populating textfields (w/out access to a viewDidLoad or similar method) on Mac Desktop

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, interface-builder, desktop-application

I have a mainMenu.xib - that sets up all my interface items (button, textfields, etc).

I have a LogController that has access to all these items via IBOutlet and IBAction.
Works fine - All connected and running well.

However, I want to have NSUserDefault values pre-populated in the textfields. However, I can't figure out how - since my LogController doesn't extend a UIViewController (Like in the iPhone world) - I don't have access to delegate methods like viewDidLoad - etc - where I could put this type of logic.

I can't put it in here (since this doesn't have access to the UI elements in IB):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application 
}
```

So for desktop applications on mac, how do I got about solving this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
```

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?AwakeFromNib